# Error while creating PowerPoint Automation Service Application SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, error, powerpoint-services

I am getting an error while trying to create a service application for PowerPoint Automation Service

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> New-SPPowerPointConversionServiceApplication -Name "PowerPoint Automation Service" -ApplicationPool "SharePoint Web Services Default"
```

> New-SPPowerPointConversionServiceApplication : Invalid application
>   pool specified At line:1 char:1
>   + New-SPPowerPointConversionServiceApplication -Name "PowerPoint Automation Servic ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Offic...viceApplicat
>   ion:NewSPPowerPoint...viceApplication)
>   [New-SPPowerPoin...viceApplication]   , InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.PowerPoint.PowerShell.Ne
>   wSPPowerPointConversionServiceApplication

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the name of an existing application pool, the one from the TechNet article is just an example that should be replace with an existing one.

To get a list of the application pools in your environment you can use `Get-SPServiceApplicationPool` detailed here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607544.aspx